# Do I need a telephony router to use CUCM

Tags: cisco

My Cisco telephony router is loud and is currently using CME, I wondered if using CUCM I can use my 1841 router that doesn't support telephony

Or does cucm need a telephony/voice router to work?

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question? CUCM and CME (CCME) are both *CALL MANAGERS*. They can work 100% independent of each other. In other words, run your two phones from one or the other, and stop asking about *both*.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUCM is not a single device, it is a software suite for controlling large enterprise telephony.  You still need gateways, etc., so your router will not be enough.

It would be like building a railroad when a bicycle would suffice.

Comment: Indeed. CUCM could replace a small telco. (if all your phones are IP - SCCP, SIP, etc. - then you won't necessarily need an analog gateway)